# Using LabelEncorder i am trying to change the dataset from String to Numeric

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have 2 dataset train_df and test_df. I need to change the columns ('ReqName','AreaChange', 'CodeChange','TestSuite') as Numeric. Hence i have used LabelEncorder , while doing so, i get below error

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = [train_df, test_df]
cols = ( 'ReqName','AreaChange', 'CodeChange','TestSuite')

for c in cols:
    lbl = LabelEncoder() 
    lbl.fit(list(data[c].values)) 
    data[c] = lbl.transform(list(data[c].values))
```

**I get this error:**

> **"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"**

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the complete error trace.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access list element via `str` objects ('ReqName','AreaChange' ...)

Change `for` loop to this:

```py
for c, _ in enumerate(cols):
```

Comment: no, this will not work since OP trying to access `data` variable, so after the first 2 indexes it will fall with "out of range" error

Comment: no, this will not work since OP trying to access `data` variable, so after the first 2 indexes it will fall with "out of range" error

Answer (score 0):

your error message could not be more clear :

you are trying to access the `data` list in index `c` which is a string.

you **must** access items in list with the corresponding index - which should be integer, for example 1,2,3 etc.

so just access it with `data[1]` , `data[0]` etc.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-213a342a9f7a> in <module>()
      7 for c in cols:
      8     lbl = LabelEncoder()
----> 9     lbl.fit(list(data[c].values))
     10     data[c] = lbl.transform(list(data[c].values))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str


This is the entire Error content i got

Comment: i don't understand why are you showing that again, have you tried my solution ?

Comment: Im beginner to Python and ML , so i dont know how to do it

Comment: lets start from scratch : please edit your question with : " ** What you want to accomplish**"

Comment: data list in index 'c' should be a str.. my intention here to convert this str to numeric

Comment: but `data` and `cols` have different lengths . i don't understand what you are trying to achieve.